# Problem with getchar in C

Tags: c, getchar

I want to write a program which can:
when I enter, say "*Alan Turing*", it outputs "*Turing, A*".
But for my following program, it outputs "*uring, A*", I thought for long but failed to figure out where *T* goes.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
char initial, ch;

//This program allows extra spaces before the first name and between first name and second name, and after the second name.

printf("enter name: ");

while((initial = getchar()) == ' ')
    ;

while((ch = getchar()) != ' ')  //skip first name
    ;

while ((ch = getchar()) == ' ')
{
    if (ch != ' ')
        printf("%c", ch);  //print the first letter of the last name
}
while((ch = getchar()) != ' ' && ch != '\n')
{
    printf("%c", ch);
}
printf(", %c.\n", initial);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bug is here:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) == ' ')
{
    if (ch != ' ')
        printf("%c", ch);  //print the first letter of the last name
}
while((ch = getchar()) != ' ' && ch != '\n')
{
    printf("%c", ch);
}
```

The first loop reads characters until it finds a non-space. That's your 'T'. Then the second loop overwrites it with the next character, 'u', and prints it.
If you switch the second loop to a `do {} while();` it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
while ((ch = getchar()) == ' ')
{
    if (ch != ' ')
        printf("%c", ch);  //print the first letter of the last name
}
```

This part is wrong. The `if` in there will never match, because that block is only run if `ch == ' '`.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) == ' ');
printf("%c", ch);  //print the first letter of the last name
```

should fix it.

Note that `getchar` returns an `int`, not a char. If you want to check for end of file at some point, this will byte you if you save `getchar`'s return value in a `char`.

Comment: +1 "If you want to check for end of file". If you want to? I would class it as essential. `ch` should be declared as `int` and every loop needs to check for `EOF`. As it stands the code has numerous opportunities for disappearing off into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using getchar() to read a string from the standard input is not really efficient. You should use read() or scanf() to read the input into a buffer an then work on your string.
It will be much easier.

Anyway, I added a comment where you bug is.

```
while((ch = getchar()) != ' ')  //skip first name
    ;

// Your bug is here : you don't use the character which got you out of your first loop.

while ((ch = getchar()) == ' ')
{
    if (ch != ' ')
        printf("%c", ch);  //print the first letter of the last name
}
```

Comment: "Using getchar() to read a string from the standard input is not really efficient." Really?

Comment: +1 @Charles, and also `read` is not in the Standard C library (it is POSIX) and `scanf()` is notoriously difficult to use correctly.